# Story of unexpectedly high (400+) Elo rising in few months (reaching 2500 Elo mark)

Tags: elo, cheating

I'm sorry for being vague, but that's exactly my problem: I can't find an online blog post of a German/Scandinavian master anymore which illustrated a case of a young boy from Eastern Europe who managed to reach 2500 mark (in a few months time span) thanks to some suspect tournaments and timing.
His coach fine-tuned everything to exploit the delay in updating the Elo list, combined with an excellent performance on a local tournament.

Does anyone can recall a similar story?

I'd really love to read the post again. It was backed up with data from the FIDE official site.

Comment: If you are looking for the name of the player, it was Stefan Macak from Slovakia. But your tag "cheating" is really not what he did!!! He just learned chess and played one game a day, for whole rating period, flying all over the world.

Comment: Maybe you are after different story. But this one was very funny and no cheating included.

Comment: Uhm.. if I remember correctly it was a more recent event, and also the name doesn't ring the bell.

Comment: I dont think that 400 elo rise is impossible in say 6 months, but its definitely very very very hard, and requires a lot of commitment, time and natural talent, which by itself will make it impossible for most people.

Comment: @Isac IMHO it's not possible to go from 2100 to 2500 in 6 months, there's simply too much to learn and absorb. I agree with you if we're speaking about under 2000 Elo rise.

Comment: He could've mastered chess, then went on to play FIDE rated tourneys. If Carlsen had never played a FIDE tourney before, but mastered the game on online platforms, he would easily reach his current rating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I finally got it!!!
Here is the link I've been looking for:
[Zibbit's blog](http://zibbit64.blogspot.com/2010/12/curious-case-of-alexandru-crisan.html)